# c++ how to hide observer implementation

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

I am designing some kind of observer pattern for my project, the problem is I don't want my `Observee` derived classes exposing to public it's methods like `attachObserver(...)` or `detachObserver(...)`.
Only my "Observer" classes needs to access these methods.

I give you an example:

```
template <typename O>
class Observee {
public:
    std::set<O*> getObservers() const;
    virtual void attachObserver(O* observer);
    virtual void detachObserver(O* observer);
private:
    std::set<O*> m_Observers;
};

class SomeObserveeClass : public Observee<SomeObserverClass> {


}
```

(I don't need `Observer` class in my case, because all my "Observers" (classes I am passing to template of Observee) have not much in common)

What I would like is that `SomeObserveeClass` does not expose it's `Observee` methods (`attachObserver`, `detachObserver`). The only class requiring to access them is the "Observer" (the class of Observee template)

The only solution I have come up with is privatize `attachObserver` and `detachObserver` and let all `Observee` be friend with their respective "Observer" but it's doesn't sound right to me.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can add one level of indirection for the friendship. `Observee` can be made friend of a wrapper class, which is in turn friend of the observer class, that only have these two functions as static private members.

Comment: I generally like the question. Seems like a question that'd have related questions and answers though. Have you searched around (i.e. googled or used some other search engine) for answers already? If so, please link what you've found and explain how they still don't answer your question.

Comment: Why doesn't it sound right? It is the solution to the problem. Just type `friend O;` in the class definition of the `Observee` template.

Comment: @ChristianHackl this would be an elegant solution, but friend class doesn't seem to work with templates. And even if it did work friend class definitions are not inherited to derived classes.

Comment: @kholm: 1.) Friend does work with templates. You should show us the code which doesn't work so we can tell you how to fix it. 2.) Why would a derived class need the functions anyway? I was just asking you why they are `virtual`. They work with the set in the base class, and even if the set was accessible in derived classes, it is hard to imagine why a derived class should override them.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You were right the template friend classes works ... (my IDE's bad intellisense thing was showing an error but in fact it's compiling.)

Answer (score 0):

> The only solution I have come up with is privatize `attachObserver` and `detachObserver` and let all `Observee` be friend with their respective "Observer" but it's doesn't sound right to me.

That's what `friend` is for. Just do it. There is no reason to feel bad about enhancing your encapsulation.

If you are worried about increased coupling, then consider this: every `Observee` class (i.e. every template instantiation) is already coupled to its `O` class. A `friend` declaration would not add a dependency which wasn't already there.

```
template <typename O>
class Observee {
public:
    // ...
private:
    friend O;

    void attachObserver(O* observer);
    void detachObserver(O* observer);

    std::set<O*> m_Observers;
};
```

The caveat is that `O` can now also access `m_Observers` directly. You must decide whether that's worth it.

---

What does strike me strange about your code is that `attachObserver` and `detachObserver` are `virtual`. Why is that? They are meant to operate on the `m_Observers` container, which is only accessible in the base class. And how would derived-class implementations differ anyway? One function adds to the set, the other one removes from it. That's not a sensible customisation point.

So just make the functions non-`virtual`. This also turns the problem of non-inherited friendship into a non-issue.

What's missing in your example is some kind of `notifyObservers` function. It should be `protected`, and non-`virtual` as well.

Comment: I made it virtual because some of my derived Observee's do some extra stuff when a new Observer is attached to them. But yes I could change that and do the extra stuff from where I call

Comment: @kholm: "do some extra stuff" sounds like you are calling the base-class implementation from the derived-class implementation. That's very bad style because the compiler won't notice if you forget to make the call. A better design is to make two private virtual hook functions, which are called by the two non-virtual functions. Something like `afterAttachObserver` and `afterDetachObserver`. Depending on what exactly you are doing, you might come up with better names.

Answer (score 0):

To C++ is not possible. Unlike Java language there's no package scope available, so use friend classes or just leave its functions public.

*If you want to limit the scope one possible way is using* ***namespaces***.

The use of template at this case no make sense for me, because templates goal is reuse the same algorithm independent of any kind of type.

If you need to add specific features to a hierarchy just use classes.